# React & Socket.io: How to detect when user redirects to another route before actually redirecting

Tags: reactjs, sockets, react-hooks, socket.io, routes

Socket.io beginner here. I'm building a practice chat app using react and socket.io and was wondering how to detect and emit an event when someone clicks on another route before them actually being redirected. I would use this to remove them from the online list in that room but not remove everywhere like the built in disconnect. I have searched other questions and tried the code below but it only gets called on the initial mount

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function SomeComponent() {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Location changed');
  }, [location]);

  ...
}
```

I'm kind of looking for something like

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if(location.path !== currentPath) {
    socket.emit('remove_user', {})
    }
}, [something])
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to put that useEffect on the root component, the App.js for example, if you don't already. [Try it](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sun-4pb5uy?file=/src/App.js).

In the example I put it on the App and it work fin, but when I put it the PostMain component it only work when i navigate to /post

Comment: Hey dude. I'm still a beginner in react but it seems that the useEffect gets called after redirect. I kind of need something that runs before redirect.

Comment: Lets say we have the following routes
/posts witch renders the Post component
/ Witch renders the Home component
If you put that useEffect in the Post component it will only be executed when you navigate to /posts url, and same thing if you put it in Home component, it will only be executed on / url.